# Why is "Kore de ii" correct?

Tags: grammar, particle-で

So I've learned that the de particle is used to indicate the location where an action takes place or indicate the means by which something is done.

However in "Kore de ii" Kore is neither the means nor the location of an action.
Why is "Kore de ii" correct?